# Automatically deploying changes to a web application

Tags: database, deployment, reporting-services, web-applications

What's the best way to automatically deploy changes to a database driven web application? Is there a single product out there that can modify the following...

1. Website (dlls, aspx, css files etc)
2. Database Schema (add tables, columns,  etc)
3. Database data (modify table contents)
4. Reporting Services reports

I've seen various separate products, but not one that does everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a Powershell method posted at  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/DeploySite.aspx

note: in addition, for the schema stuff you might need to upload a schema.version file and then have a process up on that server detect a new schema file was uploaded and apply it.  for new database rows you could maybe do something similar.  another idea is that you could run the SQL database as a webservice and talk to it direct with your powershell script.